# Tell WP register script to load a script only when the entire page is loaded

Tags: php, functions, javascript, wp-register-script

When not in WordPress we can tell a script to load when the entire page has loaded like this :

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

But is this achievable through this function (when we use this function):

```
wp_register_script
```

## Additional information

This is how currently i am enqueuing →

```
function custom_theme_js() {
    wp_register_script(
        'infinite_scroll',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );

    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'infinite_scroll' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js' );
```

Answer (score 3):

`wp_register_script()` is for telling WordPress about script *files*, and is a PHP function. It has no control over how the script executes, only where the `<script></script>` tag is output and what the URL is.

If you don't want the script to execute until the page is loaded you need to put that JavaScript you posted in the relevant script file.

Comment: Okies, but the same function tells that Hey javascript load only when JQuery is loaded.

Comment: No, it just tells it to place the _tag_ for your script after jQuery's. It doesn't change anything about the script's execution at all. When loading scripts synchronously that's good enough. Similarly, if you set the `$footer` argument of `wp_register_script()` to `true` then you can have the script tag load in the footer, which is late enough for most scripts.